# Relation between convergence of two series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $ ( a_n )_{n \in \mathbb {N}} $ a sequence of real numbers such that $ a_n \ge 0 \ \forall n $. If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac {\sqrt {a_n}}{n} $ converges, is true that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n $ converges?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Take this counterexample:
$$a_n=\frac 1n$$

**Added** Notice that the converse is true using:

$$\frac{\sqrt {a_n}}{n}\le \frac12\left(a_n+\frac1{n^2}\right)$$

Comment: For the converse I used cauchy-schwarz ineq. Nice :)

Comment: I prefer the AM-GM ineq. Thanks:)

Comment: You were busy here yesterday!